# Change recursive .then to async/await

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, ecmascript-next

I have js recursive fn like this

```
const recur = () => {
  fetchSomething().then( res => {
    if(typeof res.data == 'undefined'){ recur() }
    else { console.log(res.data) }
  })
}
recur()
```

Can I apply above code to Async/Await style?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to `return` the promise and `return recur()`?

Comment: This code is normally work in my project, now. I am only need change it to async/await @Bergi **But In the future I am not sure**

Comment: Why do you *need* to change it? `then` works totally fine in ES8 as well. But if you want to improve the code, I'd say that returning the promises for chaining and error handling purposes is more important than syntactic sugar

Comment: `res.data === undefined`

Comment: Thank for new knowledge use while instead of recursion. And `res.data === undefined` @torazaburo

Answer (score 1):

`torazaburo` and `robertklep` both rightfully recommend using a while instead to achieve this. Ill add the comments here so they dont get missed as they make good points.

> IMHO the non-recursive solution should be the preferred one. The nature of promises and `then` sort of requires the pseudo-recursive solution, but one of the great advantages of `await` is that it allows us to write asynchronous code in synchronous-like fashion.

---

```
const recur = async () => {
    const res = await fetchSomething();

    if (!res.data)
        recur();
    else
        console.log(res.data);
}
```

Something like that should do the trick.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3f4o3sdL/)

Comment: Or use a `while` loop instead of recursion.

Comment: Yup that would work also. Some form of max re-try's would be a good idea, and a cool off period would probably not hurt either.

Comment: IMHO the non-recursive solution should be the preferred one. The nature of promises and `then` sort of requires the pseudo-recursive solution, but one of the great advantages of `await` is that it allows us to write asynchronous code in synchronous-like fashion.

Comment: @torazaburo Yay for using synchronous-like fashion instead of callbacks, but I don't see why an imperative and mutation-requiring `while`-loop should be preferred over plain and functional recursion :-D

Comment: @Bergi For the same reasons one might write a for loop around an await instead as a more readable alternative to chaining promises.